# Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater

Tags: java, ionic, cordova

Querio lanzar los comandos:

```
ionic build android
```

ó

```
ionic run android --device
```

pero siempre me lanza este eror:

```
Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
```

la version de java que tengo es 1.8.0_111, tengo las variables de entorno definidas, pero no se porque me da este error. Volvi a desargar el jdk para ver si eso me solucionaba el error como lo leí en otras paginas y tengo el sdk de android asi que no tengo ni idea de porque el error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumo que tenes el JDK 8 pero que has instalado un JRE adicional en otra versión. Considera que el JDK ya trae incluido un JRE.

Dos soluciones posibles:

1. Es necesario eliminar la carpeta android carpeta de la plataforma y ejecutar execute ionic run android esto reinstalará la plataforma automáticamente y construir desde cero. Creo que los archivos de caché son el problema..
2. Volvé a bajar Android Studio. Proba una simple aplicación que ejecute un hola mundo en Java. Luego instala todo lo necesario para ionic y cordova. Ejecuta tu código y ve si te funciona.

Fijate en este [link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-requirements-check-failed-for-jdk-1-8-or-greater/68734/2) que te puede ayudar.

Comment: Acabo de editar esa frase, ahora sí guarda sentido.

Comment: Muchas gracias, en el link encotre la solución

Comment: @Fabian. Por nada. ¿Cual de todas las soluciones de ese link?

Comment: @josego Exactamente este: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-requirements-check-failed-for-jdk-1-8-or-greater/68734/15, al parecer habia un conficto con todas las versiones de jdk que tenia en el equipo.

Answer (score 3):

Hice lo siguiente, ejecuté:

```
alternatives --config java
```

Obtuve dos:

```
jdk1.7.../java y jdk1.8.../java
```

Estaba correctamente seleccionada la versión 1.8

Entonces ejecuté:

```
alternatives --config javac
```

¡`javac`, no `java`! (El compilador)

Solo existía la alternativa ***jdk1.7..../javac***.

Busqué cómo instalar una nueva alternativa y se hace así (el último parámetro seguramente será diferente en cada caso):

```
alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/... jdk 1.8..../javac
```

Luego ejecuté:

```
alternatives --config javac
```

Entonces, seleccioné la alternativa recién instalada, ¡y ya pude generar el *APK*!